CSRF token problem in login post request in React.js and Express.js
my server.js code:
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const sql = require("mssql");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const createDOMPurify = require("dompurify");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"); // Import cookie-parser
const cors = require("cors"); 
const csrf = require("csurf");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const window = new JSDOM("").window;
const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);


const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./../certs/cert.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./../certs/cert.crt"),
};

app.use(express.json());

const jwtSecret = "Snq9wE7pKDz4Txu8!2vG5rLm";

const config = {
  user: "server_admin",
  password: "~~8#UC~xDzO?",
  server: "fjord.database.windows.net",
  database: "fjord",
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
  },
};

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);
    console.log("Connected to the database successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to the database: ", error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

connectToDatabase();

function sanitizeInput(input) {
  return DOMPurify.sanitize(input);
}
console.log("Server starting..."); // Log server start

// Before any middleware (log every request)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Request received:", req.method, req.url);
  next();
}); 
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  })
);
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  // Define csrfProtection
  cookie: {
    key: "_csrf",
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "Strict",
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "true",
  },
});
app.use(csrfProtection);

app.get("/api/csrf-token", (req, res) => {
  const token = req.csrfToken();
  res.cookie("_csrf", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "Strict",
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "true",
  });
  res.json({ csrfToken: token });
});


app.post("/api/login", csrfProtection, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Reached /api/login handler");

    const csrfToken = req.headers["x-csrf-token"];
    console.log("req.csrfToken():", req.csrfToken());

    if (!csrfToken || csrfToken !== req.csrfToken()) {
      console.log("CSRF token mismatch");
      return res.status(403).send("Invalid CSRF token");
    }

    const { username, password} = req.body;

    // Create a new SQL request object
    const request = new sql.Request();
    request.input("username", sql.NVarChar, username);
    const query = `
        SELECT user_id, username, password_hash
          FROM dbo.Users
         WHERE username = @username
        `;

    const result = await request.query(query);

    if (result.recordset && result.recordset.length > 0) {
      const user = result.recordset[0];

      const hashedPassword = user.password_hash;

      const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword);

      if (passwordMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.user_id }, jwtSecret);

        res.cookie("authToken", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
          sameSite: "Strict",
        });

        res.json({ token });
      } else {
        res.status(401).send("Incorrect password");
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("User not found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during login:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error during login");
  }
});

my log in page code:
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [csrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState(""); // Add csrfToken state
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCsrfToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://localhost:5000/api/csrf-token",
          {
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        );
        setCsrfToken(response.data.csrfToken);
        console.log("CSRF token fetched:", response.data.csrfToken);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching CSRF token:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchCsrfToken();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleSubmit function started");
    try {
       console.log("Sending login request with token:", csrfToken);
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://localhost:5000/api/login",
        { username, password },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log("Login response:", response);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = response.data;
        // Cookies.set("authToken", data.token, { expires: 7, path: "/" });
        console.log("Login successful:", data);
        alert("Login successful!");
        navigate("/home");
      } else {
        console.error("Unexpected server response:", response);
        alert("Login failed. Please check your credentials.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Axios error:", error); 
      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Error response from server:", error.response.data);
        alert(`Login error: ${error.response.data.message || "Server error."}`);
      } else {
        alert("An error occurred during login. Please try again.");
      }
    }
  };


here I even added  console.log("Reached /api/login handler"); to the app.post to see if it works or no but what im getting is this error:
error
but the thing is that the token actually matches with the csrf token in the cookies
enter image description here
and in the networking tab in the log in post request headers the x-csrf-token is right:
enter image description here
and i want to know why im getting that error, post request is not even happening
i tried to remove the csrf middleware to see if i can send a post request and i was able to do it, but when i have that token logic it doesnt even send the post request and i dont see any problem in the code but idk.
